# Is it possible to have a layout be parallax in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, parallax

I know how to use the CoordinatorLayout with CollapsingToolbarLayout to make it so that the toolbar and an imageview behaves as parallax but is there a way to make it so that an entire layout behaves as a parallax? or an imageview is the image that is pinned?

I'm trying to make it so that the toolbar in the background does not collapse completely the contents still scroll over the layout if that makes sense.

Comment: This might help You...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387730/is-it-possible-to-do-a-simple-image-view-parallax-with-coordinator-layout-withou

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do a simple image view parallax with coordinator layout without the collpsing toolbar layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387730/is-it-possible-to-do-a-simple-image-view-parallax-with-coordinator-layout-withou)